# Query to delete duplicates is generating an error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete duplicates from a table based on the customer phone number. The inner select query below correctly selects all duplicate records which I need to delete, however the outter delete query generates the following error:

```
You can't specify target table 'customers' for update in FROM clause
```

Query:

```
DELETE FROM customers WHERE id IN (SELECT id from customers GROUP BY phone HAVING COUNT(phone) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In an `update` and `delete` statement, you often cannot reference the table being modified.  An easy solution is to use a `join`:

```
DELETE c
    FROM customers c JOIN
         (SELECT phone, COUNT(*) as cnt
          FROM customers c
          GROUP BY phone
         ) p
         ON c.phone = p.phone AND cnt > 1;
```

Note that this deletes *all* duplicates from the table.  Normally, you want to keep one of them:

```
DELETE c
    FROM customers c LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT phone, MIN(id) as minid
          FROM customers c
          GROUP BY phone
         ) p
         ON c.id = p.minid
    WHERE p.phone IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Also tried the following, `DELETE FROM customers 
GROUP BY phone HAVING COUNT(phone) > 1`, any idea why that won't work either?

Comment: Your first solution selects way more than duplicate phone numbers, the second solution, I am not